# How to manipulate selected values in semantic ui dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I am working on a multi select Semantic UI dropdown and want to pass the **value and text** of the selected options to an action creator.

The markup for the dropdown:

```
<Dropdown
    placeholder='Campaign Exposed To'
    fluid
    search
    selection
    multiple
    options={this.state.campaigns}
    onChange={this.exposedCampaignOnChange}
/>
```

The onChange handler looks like this:

```
exposedCampaignOnChange = (e, {value}) => {
    e.persist(); // access event properties in asynchronously

    const text = e.target.textContent;
    const currentValue = value[value.length-1];

    // manipulate value array to include text too
    value[value.length - 1] = {text: text, value: currentValue};

    this.props.campaignExposedSelected(value);
};
```

This transforms the value array into collection of objects in the following format: `{text: test 1, value: 4353234}` *which is what I want*.

However, because I've changed the value **from an array of numbers to an array of objects**, the dropdown select exhibits buggy behaviour - it doesn't show the selected options in the field.

As an alternative, to avoid manipulating the value array I thought of adding the option text to its value property like so `3442332___text` (so the dropdown options will be provided an array of values in this format). Further along the line I will parse whichever info I need. I felt this wasn't very elegant so didn't pursue it.

Appreciate any assistance on how to mutate the Sementic UI Dropdown value array without breaking the dropdown.

Comment: why not create a clone of the values array and pass it in the action creator? something like
   let newValue = [...value]; 
   newValue[value.length - 1] = {text: text, value: currentValue};
   this.props.campaignExposedSelected(newValue);

Comment: The snippet only saves the last clicked option in the desired format. The others are just values.